# PHPUnit stubs not working with array_column

Tags: php, phpunit

In my SUT, I use array_column on an array of objects to get a specific property. I need to mock the array of objects since they are fetched from the Database (which is not covered in my test).

However I noticed that array_column is not working properly on that array. Whereas in php any class with properties will successfully give array_column the desired property.

```
        $myStub = $this->getMockBuilder('DbClass')
                ->disableOriginalConstructor()
                ->getMock();
        $myStub->conversation_id = 1;
        $myStubArray = [$myStub];
        print_r(array_column($myStubArray, 'conversation_id')); //Printing empty array
```